# std::cin failure leading to looped if statement in while loop

Tags: c++, error-handling, cin, numeric-limits

So I figure I'll put this here since I had to traverse a lot of docs and forums to find the definitive answer. I was trying to get input from the user and check if the input was an integer using `isdigit()` in an if statement. If the if statement failed the program would output an error message. Although, when a nondigit character was entered the program would loop through the error message endlessly. Here's that code:

```
int guess = -1;
while (game.getCurQuestion() <= 4) {
    std::cout << "Guess: " << game.getCurQuestion() + 1 << std::endl;
    std::cin >> guess;
    if(isdigit(guess))
    {
        game.guess(guess);
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Error\n"; //this would be looped endlessly
    }
    
}
std::cout << "You got " << game.getCorrect() << " correct"  << std::endl;
return 0;
```

}

NOTE: Solved, only posted to include my solution. Feel free to correct if I stated anything incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

The posted way will fail sometimes and will cast the doubles to integers if any doubles are input.

Use something like the following

```
int getIntInput() {
    try {
        std::string input;
        std::cout << "\nPlease Enter a valid Integer:\t";
        std::cin >> input;
        size_t takenChars;
        int num = std::stoi(input, &takenChars);
        if (takenChars == input.size()) return num;
    } catch (...) {}
    return getIntInput();
}
```

Comment: I like this one as it also avoids the cin loop when a char is input. It definitely looks a lot better than the weird cin.ignore statement. My only question is I heard it was bad practice to use catch(...) is it considered acceptable in this use case?

Comment: @CrypticEthosIt's not bad here because I know the cause of the exception and try to get a new input that avoids giving the same exception.

Comment: Ahh I see makes sense originally in my code I actually had a try catch but took it out because of the (...), thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Problem: The program kept hold of the non-integer value stored in the cin buffer. This leads to the program never leaving the error message.

Solution:

1. Use `std::cin.fail()` to check if the input matches the variable data type. I.E. `int` was the expected input but the user entered a `char`. In this case `std::cin.fail()` would be true.
2. In the case of `std::cin.fail()`, use `std::cin.clear()` and `std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<int>::max(), 'n')` `std::cin.clear()` will clear the error flag. The `std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<int>::max(), 'n')` will ignore any other input that is not an integer and will skip to the new line. Effectively progressing the program.

The solution implemented in my code looks like this:

```
int guess = -1;
while (game.getCurQuestion() <= 4) {
    std::cout << "Guess: " << game.getCurQuestion() + 1 << std::endl;
    std::cin >> guess;
    if (std::cin.fail())
    {
        std::cout << "Please enter a valid number\n";
        std::cin.clear();
        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<int>::max(), '\n');
    }
    game.guess(guess);
}
```

Hope this helps and that it saves some people the tedious research because of never learning `std::cin` error handling! Note: I'm aware my implementation skips the current move, call it punishment ;)

Comment: Note: asmmo gave a very good response above that negates the need for the std::cin.clear() and std::cin.ignore(), which also prevents doubles from being entered in this use case